# How to refresh a window in C#/WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, window, refresh, textblock

I want to change a value (textBlock) according to an event. Then, I want to refresh my window, but I couldn't. I used invalidateVisual as well as solutions of other posts, but nothing worked.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why do you need to "refresh" the window? That requirement tells me you are doing it very, very, *wrong*. Moreover; how do you know its not working?

Comment: I am trying to create an agenda and I want to show info for a contact after clicking it. To be more specific, I have at the left part of the window a contact list and when an item of them I will show appropriate info at the right part.

Comment: Thats a binding alright; you don't need `InvalidateVisual` or similar.

Comment: You need to show the code. Normally, changing the `Text` property (or any other property that affects its visual state for that matter) of a `TextBlock` would automatically cause the element to be redrawn. If that's not happening, you've got code interfering with that process somehow. But without a good code example, no one can tell you what's wrong. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3):

Several solutions (the first and second one does not make use of databinding).

```
 txtMyControl.text = "New value";
```

If not on the main thread, you could use the dispatcher to update the value.

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => txtMyControl.text == "New Value")
```

However, the most WPF friendly way to do it is to use the databinding. 
Any change made to the value in code will be instantly reflected in the UI.

XAML

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtExample"  Text="{Binding MyTextProperty,Mode=TwoWay}" Height="24" Width="120"/>
```

In your code, you have to declare a variable that will be persistent.

```
private ExampleModel _ExampleModel = new ExmampleModel();
```

When you load your code, you associate that variable to your textbox data context.

```
txtExample.DataContext = _ExampleModel
```

Then, you have the class that will contains all the editable properties on screen (textboxes, radio boxes, etc...)

```
public class ExampleModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

private string _MyTextProperty = "test";
public string MyTextProperty {
    get { return _MyTextProperty; }
    set {
        if (string.Compare(_MyTextProperty, value) != 0) {
            _MyTextProperty = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyTextProperty");
        }
    }
}

public void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null) {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged;
public delegate void PropertyChangedEventHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e);
}
```

Whenever you handle your event, you just have to change the value of the property containing the information and the UI will refresh accordingly. Also, since we use a two-way binding, the value from your textbox will always be the same than the one contained by MyTextProperty property in ExampleModel class, which make value retrieval very easy.
ex:

```
_ExampleModel.MyTextProperty = "New value";
```

If you were already using databinding, make sure the class used implements INotifyPropertyChanged and that the propertyChanged event is called when the property value change or otherwise it won't update the UI.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach to what you're trying to do would be to use Data Binding.

You need to have a string object that will always hold the value of your textblock. Next you need to bind that object to your textblock and then use the event provided by the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and each time the value changes its representation (the textblock) will change to, no need to refresh the window.

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the non-existent question. Its good advice though.

Comment: Could you be kind of more polite and show respect to people start now C#/WPF?

Comment: @Vasileios Not sure who you were addressing here; but this post seems very polite and respectful. My comment was directed at the OP (and you *still* haven't really asked a question; you sort of did in your comment, but such details should be edited in). Honestly, I don't see how my comment was rude/disrespectful either. Please do take the advice in both answers though.

Answer (score 0):

If your event updates the textblock and the textblock you are using is bound to a string property and that property issues a NotifyPropertyChanged() in it's set method, that will cause the display to refresh as you desire.

There are other ways, but this is the easiest given my understanding of your question.

(this is similar to the other answer, but I tried to word so it is easier to understand/implement.)